# Neo4j Query response time is too high

Tags: neo4j

I have around 4 million nodes on a server having memory 3.5Gb . Everytime I fire a query,  CPU% goes to 100% and response takes atleast 10+ seconds! What should I do to improve response time? Bigger Server?

Comment: I read on neo4j blog, we can load complete graph in memory and skip GC from removing it. For this how much memory is required?

Comment: How does your query look like? Also provider more info on your graph model.

Comment: Like @StefanArmbruster said, what kind of queries are you doing? Have you added indexes to your data? Have you tuned your JVM to use your 3.5Gb?

Comment: Yes, Query fetches top 5 3rd degree paths between 2 given nodes in the graph. Yes indexing is done. And yes tried to tune JVM, with 1gb for Heap and tried different GC mechanisms as explained in the manual. But none seems to work efficiently.

Comment: What distribution of Neo4j are you using? Take a look at this guide to better understand hardware sizing: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/

Comment: I have moved to 16gb server and assigned 8gb heap size. According to this calculator, my db will need around 11-12 gb heap size. It is working for now, but I am worried it might get stuck in time. Not sure what to do when that happens- when GC interferes, memory is full and swapping needs to be done :-\

Comment: Please provide your concrete query, your concrete data model and a copy of your neo4j configuration and graph.db/messages.log Otherwise no one can help you.